# Angular 6 css is not showing

Tags: css, angular6

I am trying to add a css class dynamically using javascript classList. I can add class to my element and I have added my css inside style.css. When I am running npm start I can see mystyle inside styles.js. But it is not working I can't see mystyle working, here is my code.

```
 appendToContainer() {
let map = document.getElementById("biharsvg") as HTMLObjectElement;
let svgDoc = map.contentDocument; // should be fine
let echamparan = svgDoc.getElementById("echamparan");
echamparan.classList.add("mystyle");
console.log(echamparan);
}
```

This is my code I am adding a click event on a button and I am adding class called mystyle inside my element. And I have added .mystyle class inside style.css and I change browser restarted ng srve many times cleared cache. I can see mystyle inside style.js which angular generates.

When I add .mystyle using inspect element it works. What is the best solution.

Comment: add your @componet decorator code to inspect.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: @Component({ }) in your component.ts file .